# What is different about the CMake command configure_file on Windows?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

On linux I am using a command such as:

```
configure_file(dot_alpha_16.bmp test/dot_samples/dot_alpha_16.bmp COPYONLY)
```

to copy some unit test files to the build directory. On windows the files aren't getting copied. Is there a specific reason why this happens?

Comment: The documentation (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:configure_file) says that the input and output must have full paths. It seems that in your code you are using relative path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to [specify the complete directory path](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:configure_file). The following works on Windows and takes out-of-source builds into account too:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dot_alpha_16.bmp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test/dot_samples/dot_alpha_16.bmp COPYONLY)
```