# cmake to place the intermediate files to a certain directory

Tags: c++, c, cmake, build-automation

I am pretty new to cmake and wonder how I can do this is cmake. I want to place all the intermediate files (like the .o files) to be placed in a certain directory (say "build") and then once the build is done I want copy certain files I need (e.g., the .exe, .dll like the end product) from build directory to "stage" directory. how can I specify the path to these two directories (build and stage)? Cmake will also check if the build/stage directory exists or not. If does not exist, it will create the directories for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you asking is the most often CMake use case.

To make whole build process to occur in arbitary dir, you should run `cmake /path/to/your/project` from that dir (or use cmake-gui).

Your source dir would be untouched until you explicitly tell CMake to output some files there.

As for point 2:

You should place `install()` invocations into your CMakeLists.txt (see documentation on `install()`) and set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to the dir where you wish files to be copied. After that you can run `make install` or `cmake -P cmake_install.cmake` from your build dir to install these files.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach.

1. make out-of-source builds [see here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F), so that all your build stuff is in an own folder
2. copy your executables from your build directory in an own folder with explicit copying [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593881/cmake-how-to-make-a-script-for-copying-data-files-accompanying-my-program)

Or instead of choosing step 2 you also can provide an install routine where the needed executables are installed in a give path. [see here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Install_Commands)