# How to specify the path for .lib files in cmake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to build a project with `cmake`. In that i mentioned seperate folders for `.dll` and `.lib`. Dll's are created in the folder which i mentioned but `.lib` files are not generated in the folder which i mentioned. Please give a solution for this problem.

The command which i used in `cmakelists.txt` is :

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY My_Lib)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(MyApi PROPERTIES 
                                    LINKER_LANGUAGE CPP 
                                    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY My_Binary
                                    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY My_Lib)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from the CMake docs:

> For DLL platforms the DLL part of a shared library is treated as a
>   runtime target and the corresponding import library is treated as an
>   archive target.

So instead of setting `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` or `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` you need to set [`ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt:ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) or [`CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) (one of the two suffices).

Comment: Thanks it is working. But how to specify the seperate directory for intermediate directories (.dir).

Comment: You only have very little influence on the layout of the generated intermediate files. However, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218638/cmake-to-place-the-intermediate-files-to-a-certain-directory) for why that shouldn't bother you.

Comment: I would like to place the intermediate files (like .obj and .dir which are generated at the time of build) in seperate directory.What are the target properties to set.

Comment: @123r789 As I said, you cannot do that and you shouldn't bother. Is the inability to do so causing a specific problem in your case and if so, what is it?